# How can I use bcrypt on appengine for java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, bcrypt

Are there any free implementations that will run on GAE/J?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) works great and is released under a ISC/BSD license, which means it can be used royalty-free in a commercial app.

It's a single java source file that can just be dropped into an app.  Thanks for the tip Pace!